# list.remove() not works but work when llist.remove() twice

Tags: python, list

I have list like `words = [MyOwnClass(), MyOwnClass(), None, MyOwnClass(), None]`. I wanted to delete `None`.

I tried `words.remove(None)`. but only worked when did it twice.
is this right way? or not, I want to know pythonic way.

```
class Dictionary:
    words = [Word(), Word(), None, Word(), None]

    def delete_None(self)
        self.words.remove(None)  # not works
        self.words.remove(None)  # now works
```

Comment: You have two `None`. Doing `words.remove(None)` will remove first `None` from the list. Doing it again will remove second `None`

Comment: `.remove` removes first occurence

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and read [ask], [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). 
[Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)
You can find a ton of good resources on the internet (especially the documentation for [`list.remove()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_remove.asp) ), and possibly many questions on SO that deal with similar problems.

Comment: Wow thanks! It worked! and you are so fast loll

Answer (score 4):

If you have to do multiple removes, it is better to rebuild from scratch:

```
words[:] = (x for x in words if x is not None)
```

This is a single linear operation, while every remove itself is linear as well because of the left-shifts needed for all subsequent elements.

Also note that the slice assignment `words[:] = ...` makes this a *mutation* on the original list object (just like the `remove` calls would be), not just a *rebind* of the variable whose effects may only be local. The generator `(...)` expression instead of a list comprehension `[...]` is more space efficient as it doesn't build an intermediate list, though the comprehension might be slightly faster.

For arbitrary objects, testing equality instead of identity would often be preferable:

```
lst[:] = (x for x in lst if x != obj_to_remove)
```

Or for a more functional approach:

```
from operator import ne  # "not equal"
from functools import partial

lst[:] = filter(partial(ne, obj_to_remove), lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the Nones, you can use filter:

```
words = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, words))
```